# Different arguments for determing the date in the Mayan calendar

Tags: python

Use the function expired to write a function `mayadate()`. The function has two parameters: a parameter `date` that takes a date in the Gregorian calendar, and an optional parameter `separator` that takes a string containing a single character. The function must return the date in the Mayan calendar that corresponds to the given date in the Gregorian calendar. To determine the date in the Maya calendar, you may assume that the date 01/01/1970 in the Gregorian calendar corresponds to the date 12.17.16.7.5 in the Maya calendar. Count the number of days that have passed since this reference date, until you reach the requested date. The individual values for the time periods in the Maya calendar must be represented without leading zeroes, and are separated from one another using the given separator. If no separator was explicitly passed to the function, the function must use the same character used to separate the numbers in the given Gregorian date.

I am trying to solve the last function for different cases but it is still not working for some, for example it is not working with:

```
mayadate(date='05-0004-002294', separator='/')
```

correct answer:   `'13/14/5/6/18'`

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File <code>, line 131, in mayadate TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

If I try to solve it than some of the other cases stops working.

Other cases:

```
mayadate('5.4.2051') solution: '13.1.18.15.4'
mayadate('9+10+0002267', '|') solution: '13|12|18|9|3'
mayadate('21 12 2012', separator='+') solution: '13+0+0+0+0'
```

Can anyone help me?

```
def dmy(n):
    '''
    >>> dmy('01/01/1970')
    (1, 1, 1970)
    >>> dmy('20-7-1988')
    (20, 7, 1988)
    >>> dmy('00012+00012+02012')
    (12, 12, 2012)
    >>> dmy('21 12 2012')
    (21, 12, 2012)
    >>> dmy('26.03.2407')
    (26, 3, 2407)
    '''


    new = n.replace('/', " ")
    new2 = new.replace('-', " ")
    new3 = new2.replace('+', " ")
    new4 = new3.replace('=', " ")
    new5 = new4.replace('~', " ")
    new6 = new5.replace('.', " ")
    new7 = new6.replace('#', " ")
    new8 = new7.replace('|', " ")
    new9 = new8.replace('*', " ")
    new10 = new9.replace(':', " ")

    k = [int(s) for s in new10.split() if s.isdigit()]

    r = tuple(k)

    return r


def expired(n):
    '''
    >>> expired('01/01/1970')
    0
    >>> expired('20-7-1988')
    6775
    >>> expired('00012+00012+02012')
    15686
    >>> expired('21 12 2012')
    15695
    >>> expired('26.03.2407')
    159695
    '''

    s = dmy(n) 

    a = s[0] 
    b = s[1] 
    c = s[2] 

    from datetime import date, timedelta

    d1 = date(c, b, a)  # start date
    d2 = date(1970, 1, 1)  # end date

    delta = d2 - d1   

    return abs(delta.days)



def mayadate(*args, **kwargs):
    '''
    >>> mayadate('01/01/1970')
    '12/17/16/7/5'
    >>> mayadate('20-7-1988',separator='/')
    '12/18/15/4/0'
    >>> mayadate('00012+00012+02012',separator='-')
    '12-19-19-17-11'
    >>> mayadate('21 12 2012',separator='+')
    '13+0+0+0+0'
    >>> mayadate('26.03.2407')
    '14.0.0.0.0
    '''

    args1 = args if args else None
    args2 = [kwargs.get(i) for i in ['date', 'separator']]


    if args1 is not None:
        s = expired(args1[0]) + 1856305

    if args2[0] is not None:
        s = expired(args2[0]) + 1856305


    w = s // 144000
    q = s%144000

    v = q // 7200
    q2 = q%7200

    u = q2 // 360
    q3 = q2%360

    t = q3 // 20
    q4 = q3%20

    r = q4

    k = str()

    if args1 is not None:
        symbol = "~`|!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]:>;',</?*-+.' '"
        for i in args1[0]:
            if i in symbol:
                k = str(i)

    if args2[0] is not None:
        symbol = "~`|!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]:>;',</?*-+.' '"
        for i in args2[0]:
            if i in symbol:
                k = str(i)

    import re
    w = re.sub(r"\b0{2}", "", str(w))
    v = re.sub(r"\b0{2}", "", str(v))
    u = re.sub(r"\b0{2}", "", str(u))
    t = re.sub(r"\b0{2}", "", str(t))
    r = re.sub(r"\b0{2}", "", str(r))


    if args2 is None and len(args1) == 1:
        q = str(w) + k + str(v) + k + str(u) + k + str(t) + k + str(r)
        return q


    if len(args1) == 1 and args2[1] is None:
        q = str(w) + k + str(v) + k + str(u) + k + str(t) + k + str(r)
        return q


    else:
        q = str(w) + k + str(v) + k + str(u) + k + str(t) + k + str(r)
        char = "~`|!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]:>;',</?*-+.:' '"
        kas = ' '

        if args2[1] is not None:
            for x in q:
                if x in char or x in kas:
                    q = q.replace(x, args2[1], 4)    
            return q

        if args1 is not None:
            for x in q:
                if x in char or x in kas:
                    q = q.replace(x, args1[1], 4)    
            return q
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how to convert between Mayan and gregorian? In English, that is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your call and your args handling.

```
mayadate(date='05-0004-002294', separator='/')
```

There are no normal args: they're all kwargs.  Therefore, in your function, `args` is empty.  You convert it to `None`.  Later, you call for its length; as the error says, `len(None)` is illegal.

Decide how you want to handle that case, and change your code accordingly.